# How to properly handle multiple operations over same Socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, client

I am not an expert in networking. However, I started a big project in Java, I already made the SQL database and most of the server, I am only working with TCP at the moment, and I was using Strings as operation identifiers server-side, I don't know if this is correct but is working. Problem is there are operations that require me to send data during all the time while client is connected (like the chat I tried to implement in the last "if" sentence) and I don´t know how to implement it client-side without catching wrong information from other operations like bet results or other things. Should I just use a different port?

```
public static class Users extends Thread{
    private final Socket socket;
    private final Connection connection;
    private final DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    private final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;

    public Users(Socket socket, Connection connection) throws IOException {
        this.socket=socket;
        this.connection=connection;
        this.dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        this.dataOutputStream=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (true){
            try {
                String operation= dataInputStream.readUTF();
                if(operation.equals("Login")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("Register")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("GetClientData")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("Deposit")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("Withdraw")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("PlaceBetOnRoulette")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("PlaceBetOnCrash")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("PlaceBetOnCoinFlip")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if(operation.equals("PlaceBetOnSlot")){
                    //censored//
                }
                if (operation.equals("SendMessage")){
                    String message= new String();
                    message= dataInputStream.readUTF();
                    if (!message.equals("") && !message.isEmpty()){
                        for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                            Socket chatVolatileSocket = (Socket) arrayList.get(i);
                            DataOutputStream volatileMessageSender= new DataOutputStream(chatVolatileSocket.getOutputStream());
                            volatileMessageSender.writeUTF(message);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            arrayList.remove(socket);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you already have a communication protocol for sending different kinds of messages. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @ControlAltDel my problem is that all the other operation were linear so i knew the order of all thing i was sending and recieving, but with the chat if i send an string with a message when the client was waiting the string with the result of a bet or something like that i would pick the wrong string. Cause i don´t know when someone will send me a writeUTF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend establishing a more formal message protocol. On a project I am working on I am sending JSON with several common fields like "type" and "time" over web sockets. This can be done similarly using XML if you prefer. This way you can structure your messages.

Also, I meant add this in the comments, but I might as well include this here: Don't use Data streams. Just use plain old Input/OutputStreams. Data streams are Java-only and will lock you into choices that down the road you may very well regret.